Debugging taskmgr: spy++ says WM_LBUTTONDOWN captured but windbg doesn't break
I'm trying to reverse engineer taskmgr because
How to restart explorer like taskmgr?
and after 5 years still no one knows how it works apparently. (I want to know because it has a different behavior from using PostMessage(0x5B4) + ShellExecute("explorer.exe") or using Restart Manager)
So I tried to break on WM_LBUTTONDOWN when I right click explorer.exe -> click the "restart" button on the context menu,
and spy++ logging does record that a WM_LBUTTONDOWN is sent to the Window with class name TaskManagerWindow.
Then I tried to set a breakpoint with bp /w "@rdx == 0x201" taskmgr!6B0F0
which should break on the WNDPROC of TaskManagerWindow indicated by spy++ when the message is WM_LBUTTONDOWN.
And....., it doesn't. Meanwhile spy++ keeps printing that a WM_LBUTTONDOWN is sent to TaskManagerWindow. What gives?

"after 5 years still no one knows how it works apparently" maybe it's just because that question is not good. 1.) you don't describe what you do (e.g. on which tab you are 2.) you don't describe what you see. 3.) There is no "the explorer process". On the "processes" tab, there may be no explorer at all and on the details tab, there may be several of them. 4.) Explorer has many different settings, which may affect the behavior. Please document them. 5.) I have no "kill&start" menu. 6.) You don't describe the differences of what happens with your method and what happens with Task Manager.

Why would you start at WM_LBUTTONDOWN and not put a breakpoint when task manager starts a child process? Like sxe cpr?

Oh, I'm not the one asking that question, if you're mistaken. I immediately know what OP was talking about when I first saw it, so I consider it elaborate enough. OP even included a screenshot.
And 6 is because I don't want to clutter this post with too much information, while the main question is about Windbg.

And hey, after I posted this I eventually got some progress because I noticed taskmgr loads explorer.exe as module when it tries to restart it, so I did sxe ld:explorer.exe and got a stacktrace; though the original question still remains.

Would you elaborate sxe cpr? What sign or indication makes you think it starts a child process while trying to restart explorer? Not really familiar with reverse enginnering.

Whenever a program (A) starts another program (B), that A is the parent of B (technically), or B is the child of A (logically). AFAIK, you can't change that, and since task manager must somehow start the process, sxe cpr should work.

Update: sxe cpr doesn't break. So taskmgr isn't using CreateProcess or ShellExecute to launch explorer. More likely explorer is restarting itself.

That's possible, but somehow defeats my understanding of the purpose of Task Manager. If Explorer.exe hangs, you can't tell (via IPC) it to restart. If explorer really restarts itself, what about sxe cpr in the explorer process? You can attach to multiple processes with WinDbg.

Finally got it. You can see my answer in the other post.
